# CSS - Set parent element display none

Tags: css

I have a web code generated by an aplication (built in angular). It is a menu choice where I need to hide some of them. It looks e.g. like this:

```
<div class=first>
  <div class=second>
   <a href=href1>
  </div>
  <div class=second>
   <a href=href2>
  </div>
  <div class=second>
   <a href=href3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now what I need is to hide the div which contains a element with href2.
I can hide the a element:

```
.first .second a[href="href2"] {display:none}
```

But I need to hide the whole div element. I thought:

```
.first .second < a[href="href2"] {display:none}
```

that doesn't work.

I KNOW THE JQUERY SOLUTION with has function. The problem is I can only adapt css files of the application. If i'm right I cannot use jquery in css file.

Please...any Idea how to do this ?

thanks a lot for help

best regards
Marek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment there is (sadly) no way to adress the parent element with CSS.
I don't know your layout or CSS Code but maybe you can just structure your HTML-Code in a different way.

**Edit**
And now I understand your question...
To hide (for example) the 3th `.second` div you don't need to adress it from the child element but from the parent element.
What you are probably looking for are the `nth` selectors, 
for instance: `nth-child()` or `nth-of-type()`.
You can find more info [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp).

Also, you should probably take a look at the basics of HTML and CSS.
In your code you have not closed the `<a>` tags or wrapped the values of the attributes in quotation marks.

Wrong:

```
<div class=first></div>
```

Right:

```
<div class="first"></div>
```

To hide (for instance) the first element you could use the `:first-child` selector or the `:nth-child()` selector. Since you will probably use the `nth-child()` selector this would be:

```
.first > .second:nth-child(1) {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: The html code was just an Example. I know it is not exact. It should only explain the structure. Anyway, I know the nth-child but I cannot use that. The number of elements and position of the href2 can vary. The html is generated by a angular application so I even cannot change the code structure (it is not my application).

Comment: Well, then you HAVE to use Javascript. I know, you can't add JS-Files but there is no need for that. Just put it directly at the end of your `<body>` tag and wrap your JS in `<script>` tags. In this way you don't need to include any files. Since you can't include JQuery you will have to use vanilla JS then.

Comment: AAron thank you. My first thought was, I cannot change the body. It is generated by the angular application. But then I thought again and ... there must be some entry html or other index file. And I have access to the files of the app. So I have to search and take a look. And If I find it, I have to check about vanilla as this is new for me. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: No Problem ;). Don't forget to mark this post as solved.

Comment: Aaron I need some help with this. I am able to add some code to index.html. But I'm not able to find out how to add the vanilla code. I need to do actually display none on the following element parrent:.navigation-bar__item-menu-list.ng-scope a[href='#/create/asset']"  (so on the navigation bar). any idea please?

Comment: Yes I could help you with this. But what I will do instead is to 'teach' you the most important thing a web developer, programmer, etc. MUST be able to do:
Research!

I will give you some keywords. Those are: `querySelectorAll`, `change CSS Javascript`. If you still have questions you can ask me of course but you need to learn how to research.

Comment: This is a comment section that is not referring to your question. You will have to make a new one then.

Comment: your tip with query selector is great.i'm able to identify my element. however there is either no easy command to get the parent. one has to use a custom build function. anyway, thanks a lot :)